# 502 Proxy error when trying to use Homebrew php72 with Server.app websites

Tags: homebrew, server.app, apache, proxy, php

I'm having a puzzling issue with a website on macOS server (server.app 5.6, High Sierra 10.13).

All works fine when the url length is below 70 characters. 70 and up and I'm getting a Proxy error.
The actual absolute path char count respectively <= 94 - works, > 94 - Error

[image]

Can there be a limit set somewhere?

**EDIT**

Seems to be related to change of the PHP from system to Homebrew.

**EDIT 2**

The **OS PHP version** shipped with the Server.app is **7.1.32** – it works but is missing the **intl** extension that I need for a **Magento 2.3.3** project
(I think **intl** is shipped with the Server.app or MacOS/Xcode but inactive by default)

The **Homebrew PHP version** that I was trying to use: **7.2.25**

The **MySQL** version: **8.0.16** (Oracle community)
The MySQL actually says that it's compiled for MacOS 10.14 and I run MacOS 10.13, not sure if that is important)

**EDIT 3**

After more testing I noticed the error pops-up also with shorter, simple urls, random pages, without any pattern really (when using Homebrew PHP).

I've compared the php.ini from OS and Homebrew installations with a diff but failed to find any significant differences. The error appears even on a simple Wordpress websites that don't use any of the advanced php extensions.

I've got the same Homebrew PHP installed on my other Mac, same OS but also Homebrew MySQL and without the proxy – it works fine.

Comment: Also if someone had an advice on how to disable those proxy errors showing-up on front-end...

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger! The error is probably related to your website **and** an application server (e.g. TomCat, JBoss etc.)  or a database linked to it. What kind of website are you hosting?

Comment: @klanomath trying to host a Magento website, just noticed that the Proxy error started showing up randomly on even simple wordpress sites I also host. It started after changing the PHP from the MacOS's to Homebrew, guess I must check the PHP extensions on the OS's first and then try to set same ones up on the Homebrew (as don't know how to add extensions to OS's PHP ;-). Apart from that there is just MySQL running on the server. Btw, I prefer blank screen and logs in the front-end of the production sites ;-)

Comment: Which setup guide/how-to did you follow to set up Magento (& MySQL/PHP)? I will try to reproduce the error in a VM...

Comment: PHP: `brew install php72`; MySQL: installer downloaded from Oracle's website; Magento: Composer. Also my server has quite low memory – only 4GB Mac Mini, might be that... (has an SSD tho)

Comment: More important: did you setup the "new" website in the "server root" (/Library/...) with the Server.app or as normal website in the standard apache root at /private/.... But checking older questions of yours you've probably chosen the Server.app path.

Comment: Yes, I use server app for managing websites, DNS and certificates, my website root isn't at default location but in the home dirs of the main user. It all works fine but with the Hombrew PHP even Wordpress websites, that were working perfectly otherwise, generate the Proxy error (only when trying to access admin panel). Strange

Comment: I tried to simulate your problem in a VM but failed almost completely - the admin link after successfully setting up Magento timed out (I used brew-php72 /MySQL 8.0.16/the *composer* method to install Magento/made some adjustments to the admins PATH variable/modified the sites config file in /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/ to use brew's php72 - apparently I did something wrong). It would require to know all the mods you made (PATH/config etc. and the whole proxy config - quasi the whole recipe) to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help.I wasn't able to use the Magento's web set-up either, ended-up using CLI set-up which finished without warnings and then the site  was theoretically fine apart from those random proxy errors hunting all the necessary scripts and partials.  Yeah... It is impossible to fully emulate other's environment with limited info, I don't think I did much modding to the server.app and configs tho, but might have changed something long time ago and forgot about it. Only thing important to change in php.ini is memory_limit as Magento needs at least 786M.

Comment: Anyways, I found out that even simplest sites generate those errors when I swap to homebrew, so might try and install a different php, or figure out how to add `intl` and `opcache` to the OS's one.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get to the bottom of that... most likely the issues are related with the specific configuration of the bundled Apache server on MacOS.

I think the only solution would be re-installing Apache with eg. Homebrew, which is effectively migrating away from the outdated Server.app.